# Script for COM ports

Tags: serial-port

Is there a way to make a script for changing COM ports and to make it to run on startup?

To explain what i mean, I have a Prolific USB to Serial COM port adapter and the machine that is plugged in works if I plug it in and set it to COM4 in device manager/advanced settings.

But the problem starts after a restart and I have to change the COM port to something else eg. COM2 and change it back in order for it to work properly using COM4.

I've searched a lot about it but i can't seem to find the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reg add "Full registry device path" /v PortName /t REG_SZ /d Desired COM port /f

This is the answer to anybody that searches the interwebz ^.^